# What are good values for sample weights for UNet?

Tags: neural-networks, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement U-Net (https://arxiv.org/abs/1505.04597) from scratch using Keras.

The thing about UNet apart from its architecture, is that it's using weight-maps from the input images in the cross-entropy loss

$ CE = \sum w(x)\log(p_{l(x)}(x)) $

where $w(x)$ is the weight in the pixel $x$.

Now, the weightmaps that the authors seem, judging by the images in the paper can take values from 0 to over 10.

[image]

When I tried to pass them as sample weights in my keras model (which was training just fine without them), the model stopped converging. It actually stuck early on with non-sensical values.

The model ends up with extremely high (positive) values for the 0 class and extremely low (negative) for the 1 class, so it ends up assigning the 0 class to all the pixels.

I've tried to clip the gradients but that didn't help and the authors don't mention anything any extra step.

I'm guessing that the 0 weights, zero out the loss but if that were the reason behind the above then

1. the pixels with the high values in the weightmap would train just fine
2. the problem would get solved with some positive $\epsilon$ added to the element-wise product of the loss with the weightmap

So, which values for sample weights would be considered as "good" values and what can I do to make the model not get stuck?

Comment: A similar question is asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58134005/keras-u-net-weighted-loss-implementation). Maybe it can help you.
And this also is my problem and i'm looking to know how do we compute those weights and feed it through the network.